# Relation between Function1 and Reader Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Although I understand the implementation of the reader monad of which I give 2 of the most prominent way to do it below:

```
 case class Reader[R, A](run: R => A)
 def readerMonad[R] = new Monad[({type f[x] = Reader[R,x]})#f] {
    def unit[A](a: => A): Reader[R, A] = Reader(_ => a)
    override def flatMap[A,B](st: Reader[R, A])(f: A => Reader[R, B]): Reader[R, B] =
      Reader(r => f(st.run(r)).run(r))
  }
```

or more simply:

```
case class Reader[R, A](run: R => A) {

def map[B](f: A => B): Reader[R, B] =
    Reader(r => f(run(r)))

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Reader[R, B]): Reader[R, B] =
    Reader(r => f(run(r)).run(r))
}
```

I wonder if there is an intrinsic relationship between Reader Monad and Function1. I have been readying here and there comment hinting at that. Is Reader by definition a Function1 monad ?

I do not think so. But I would like to wrap my head around the concept.

What does it means to sequence function, when those function are of type 1 ?

That is, you take a function and you apply a function that return the same type of function. I do think Reader is a specific technics, independent of the fact that the function are function 1. Threadying the environment through is just a choice, and it could be done with FunctionN if we wanted to.

Just an intuition.

### Edit

Here is how the exercise comes in FP programming in Scala:

```
Hard: To cement your understanding of monads, 
give a monad instance for the following type, 
and explain what it means. 
What are its primitive operations? 
What is the action of flatMap? ......

case class Reader[R, A](run: R => A)

object Reader {
  def readerMonad[R] = new Monad[({type f[x] = Reader[R,x]})#f] {
    def unit[A](a: => A): Reader[R,A]
    def flatMap[A,B](st: Reader[R,A])(f: A => Reader[R,B]): Reader[R,B]
  }
}”
```

and part of the answer that leave me unsatisfied

```
// The action of Reader's `flatMap` is to pass the `r` argument along to both the
// outer Reader and also to the result of `f`, the inner Reader. Similar to how
// `State` passes along a state, except that in `Reader` the "state" is read-only.
```

I understand that as I can read code. I think that explanation falls short to answer clearly the question of the exercise. I was looking for something a bit more general than a bare description of what the code does.

For instance, what does that mean have the type R fixed. What does that means to chain computation that return as effect Function that take the same input parameter type ?

Comment: So the **Reader** monad is usually referred as mechanism for dependency injection. So for example assume you have three operations. The first one returns all users, the second one returns the city of each user, and the third one returns the country of each city. And you want to compute the number of users per country. However, all of these operations also require a connection to the database. So you may forget about that detail and rather make them return a reader from a DB connection to something. So you can compose all of those operations forgetting about the database connection, until run.

Answer (score 5):

`Reader[R, A]` is a wrapper over `R => A` (so methods can be defined just inside the class, not as extension methods for functions). A function `f` can be wrapped to a reader `Reader(f)`, a reader `r` can be unwrapped to a function `r.run`. So `Reader[R, A]` ↔ `R => A` is an isomorphism.

`Reader[R, ?]` has an instance of type class `Monad`.

`R => ?` has an instance of type class `Monad`.

Comment: What do you mean by this : (so methods can be defined just inside the class, not as extension methods for functions).

Comment: @MaatDeamon Functions do not have `map`, `flatMap`. You can define them either as extension methods for `Function1` or ordinary methods inside class `Reader`.

Comment: Let me ask it this way, what is special about function1 that as a monad it bind the parmeter of each function in the chain

Comment: @MaatDeamon now sure what your question was, care to rephrase it?

Comment: I guess i am in that thing where something probably not that complicated confuse you to the point that it is even difficult to articulate what's confusing. 

I am uncomfortable with the idea that because Function1 is Function1, if you define a monadic behavior on it, "it happens to give you a reader pattern". I wonder for example if the behavior of flatMap on function1 is what it is because it is Function1, or because we decided to implement it this way, because we new in advance what we wanted

Comment: For instance if you work with the book FP in Scala and many other, they have a tendency to tell you to follow the signature to figure out what you need to implement. So the only thing that i see leading to the implementation we have is ```Monad[({type f[x] = Reader[R,x]})#f]``` , that is the fact that Monad only take single type constructor. So on a function this means that you Bind the input of that function, in other words you can only sequence with a function that takes the same input "type".

Comment: Monad for `r => a` is defined as it is due to the fact that being a monad in `a` is the only reasonable/lawful way to define one. Ultimately, math dictates it. Having the `Reader` wrapper is just for convenience. If you want a monad in the codomain you wind up with the continuation monad for `(a -> r) -> r`.

Comment: That last comment just made thing harder 

Comment: Although thank for taking the time to write up! All of it contribute

Comment: How about something along the line (please guys I would like your opinion to see if I am getting close). Basically we are chaining (composing over) a bunch of effect that requires evaluation to return their result. The only way the all sequence of those effect can be trigger is if they have the same input pass to all of them, the flatMap only ensure that the order of the sequence is respected. In other words, once you have composed your sequence of deferred computation, there is no way than to thread the same input automatically to all of them, to be able to trigger each evaluation in chain.

Comment: Hence you can only flatMap over function that have the same input type. This along the way explains the monad fixed parameter anyway.

Comment: Therefore function1Monad is in essence a ReaderMonad and a ReaderMonad is a function1Monad ! Did I get it right ?

Comment: Yes, you can think of Reader and Function1 as equivalent (hence the comment above calling them isomorphic, which means—broadly—"they have the same shape"). One benefit to treating a function as a Reader instead of Function1 is that you can compose a bunch of readers together and then finally at the end pass the "R" parameters one time.