# How is Kleisli a monad Transformer?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

Some definition of Monad Transformers in cats.

> EitherT[F[_], A, B] is a lightweight wrapper for F[Either[A, B]] that
> makes it easy to compose Eithers and Fs together. To use EitherT,
> values of Either, F, A, and B are first converted into EitherT, and
> the resulting EitherT values are then composed using combinators.

> OptionT[F[_], A] is a light wrapper on an F[Option[A]]. Speaking
> technically, it is a monad transformer for Option, but you don’t need
> to know what that means for it to be useful. OptionT can be more
> convenient to work with than using F[Option[A]] directly.

I understand the concept, even saw some interesting talk about it: [Monad transformers down to earth by Gabriele Petronella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jd5e71nFEZM&t=0s)

I understand the Reader Monad, and how Kleisli is just a generalization.

What i do not understand is the statement bellow, that says that it is a monad transformer. What are we stacking exactly ? I don't see 2 monad being stacked here ....

> Kleisli can be viewed as the monad transformer for functions. Recall
> that at its essence, Kleisli[F, A, B] is just a function A => F[B],
> with niceties to make working with the value we actually care about,
> the B, easy. Kleisli allows us to take the effects of functions and
> have them play nice with the effects of any other F[_].

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monad transformer `EitherT[F[_], A, B]` (a wrapper for `F[Either[A, B]]`) appears when we consider composition of two monads: `F` (outer monad) and `Either[A, ?]` (inner monad).

Monad transformer `OptionT[F[_], A]` (a wrapper for `F[Option[A]]`) appears when we consider composition of two monads: `F` (outer monad) and `Option` (inner monad).

Monad transformer `Kleisli[F, A, B]` (a wrapper for `A => F[B]`) appears when we consider composition of two monads: `A => ?` (outer monad) and `F` (inner monad).

Comment: What is the monad “A=> ?” In this case

Comment: @MaatDeamon Reader https://stackoverflow.com/a/64176072/5249621

Comment: Monad type have names , like either monad and option monad or function1 monad as u suggest. Would let me know what r the name of the two type of monad being stack ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon Reader  aka Function1 (outer monad) and arbitrary monad `F` (inner monad).

Comment: @DmytroMitin This is the first time I see a transformer in the wild, which additionally doesn't look like a hack.

Comment: @scriptum Well, composition of monads is generally not a monad (while composition of functors is a functor). Monad transformers is a workaround.